# How to avoid import cycles in mock generation?

Tags: go

Simple example.

I have package xxx. This package contains:

- struct A
- interface B which is a field of A
- struct C which is an argument in method of B

  ```
  type A struct {
      SomeField B
  }

  type B interface {
      SomeMethod(c C)
  }
  ```

Now imagine I want to create unit test for structure A and mock dependency B. For creating mock I am using mock generator. All mocks are stored in the common "mocks" folder.

The problem is that generated mock has a dependency on xxx package. This is happening because SomeMethod of interface B has argument xxx.C.

Whenever I try to import my mock structure in a_test.go it fails because of cycle import problem. xxx package importing mocks package in the a_test.go. and mocks package imports xxx package in my generated mock.

I need a peace of advice, what is the best workaround for this? Maybe my approach is not idiomatic enough. Where do you store your mocks?

Comment: `xxx package importing mocks package` why ?

Comment: Because mocks package contains mock for B interface. I need it to mock dependency of struct A in a_test.go

Comment: what your saying is mock package importing xxx, im confused

Comment: Yes, because the mock for B contains method SomeMethod which has argument from package xxx (xxx.C). It should be imported.

Answer (score 16):

You need to put your test under a different package.

`a.go` is under package `xxx`

`a_test.go` is under package `xxx_test`

`a_mock.go` is under package `xxx_mock`

This way `a_test.go` will be dependent on `xxx` and `xxx_mock` and will not cause dependency cycle.

Also, `a.go` and `a_test.go` can be under the same folder, like this:

```
xxx/
  - a.go
  - a_test.go
mock/
  - a_mock.go
```

Comment: if a_test uses mock (which it would otherwise what's the point) that means I would import `mock` in xxx and in mock I am importing xxx - so here we have cycle.

Comment: @codemuncher How so? `xxx_test` only has dependency on `xxx` and `xxx_mock`, and `xxx_mock` only has dependency on `xxx`. Draw a diagram for yourself. Where is the cycle? Circular dependency between directories does not mean dependency between packages.

Comment: My comment was only for the second illustration where you say `a.go` and `a_test.go` can be under the same folder (yes I read the folder as a package because go compiler reads them as a package too. IF I tried to have `a_test.go` in the different package but the same directory then it will throw multiple packages in the same directory error).

Comment: PS: I like your idea of having `a_test.go` under different package

Answer (score 7):

Since

1. interface
2. struct
3. user code
4. unit test for the user code

are all in the same package, the interface should be considered as "in-package" interface, which is invisible for code in other package. So, the mock for this interface should be IN THE SAME PACKAGE as the interface itself.

Conclusion:

1. interface
2. struct
3. user code
4. unit test for the user code
5. mock for the interface

PUT ALL OF THEM IN THE SAME PACKAGE.

So put the mock code generated by gomock into the same package as the interface, but not "mock" package. Example(windows version):

```
mockgen -source=.\foo\bar.go -destination=.\foo\bar_mock.go -package=foo
```

Answer (score 4):

Compiling `a_test.go` as different package (ex. `a_test`) will resolve the cirucular import issue.

This is the [io_test.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19:src/io/io_test.go) example from go language source. Associate question with example by replacing package `xxx` with package `io` and `a_test` with `io_test`.

```
//io_test.go

package io_test

import{
    . "io" //wildcard import
}
// io_test code
```

However there wont be access to non-exported type in package io. To make the non-exported type to exported type we could add a file [export_test.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19:src/io/export_test.go) and define a exported and assign non-exported type to exported type.

```
//export_test.go

package io

// exported for test
var IOExportedType= ioNonExportedType
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a top level package that all other packages import from. Put your interfaces there.

For instance:

```
domain/
    interfaces.go
a/
    mock.go
b/
    mock.go
c/
    mock.go
```

`a`, `b` and `c` should import from `domain` so they don't have any dependencies on each other. You will use duck typing to implement the interfaces of the `domain` package in your mocks.

Here's an actual use case using your example:

**domain/interfaces.go**:

```
type A interface {
    Foo()
}

type B interface {
    Bar() string
}

type C interface {
    Baz() string
}
```

**a/mock.go**:

```
type A struct {
    SomeField domain.B
}

// ...
```

**b/mock.go**:

```
type B struct {
    SomeMethod(c domain.C)
}

// ...
```

**c/mock.go**:

```
type C struct {}

// ...
```

That should compile just fine, because all the mocks import from the top level `domain` package, and they all implement the respective interfaces.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of having all mocks centralized in common "mocks" folder I will have mock.go per package where all mocks of this specific package will live?

Comment: No, you can use one mock folder as well. The point here is that there is a top level `domain` package that has the "real" interfaces, and your mocks are just duck-typed implementations of those top level interfaces. This gives you the flexibility of not getting any circular dependency errors since the mocks will all import from `domain` package and won't depend on each other.

Comment: So in this case I will store all application interfaces in domain/interfaces.go instead of package to which it should logically belong? Is such approach idiomatic / frequently used?

Comment: And actually, applying your approach to my example, if I move interface B to domain package, domain will depend on xxx because interface method has xxx.C argument. And xxx should depend on domain since B is part of A. Therefore if interface B is moved to domain, C should be moved as well.

Comment: It's a [Clean Architecture](http://manuel.kiessling.net/2012/09/28/applying-the-clean-architecture-to-go-applications/) design pattern. Use it if it fits your needs, dispose of it otherwise. It is just one solution to your circular dependency problem. And in response to your last comment, yes, that is correct. My example also assumes that.

Answer (score 0):

In case of avoiding self referencing in Go 1.17

Add this arg

```
-self_package github.com/xxx
```

So

```
mockgen -source=<srcName>.go \
-package <pkgName> \
-self_package github.com/<user>/<repo>/<pkgName> \
-destination <dest>.go
```